# Using keyframes to animate a shape with clip-path and overflow hidden is glitching for me

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-animations

When the sand timer goes upside down, there's a glitchy green line.

I think it's to do with the house part (bottom half) being made up of two boxes each with a clip-path and overflow hidden, so when the sand travels outside the bounds of the inside box, it's glitching...

See below:
https://codepen.io/LewisChatham/pen/mdWYyKw

```
$time: 5s;
$color: aquamarine;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 100%;
}

.happy-home {
  animation:flip $time ease-in-out infinite;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 25%;
  left: 45%;
  overflow: hidden;
  .top {
    height: 10rem;
    width: 10rem;
    border: 1.6rem solid #000;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    &:before {
      animation:top $time linear infinite;
      background-color: $color;
      border-radius:50%;
      content:"";
      display:block;
      height:10rem;
      position:absolute;
      top: -2rem;
      left: -30%;
      width: 10rem;
    }
    &:after {
      animation:top-drip $time linear infinite;
      background-color:$color;
      content:"";
      display:block;
      height: 200%;
      left: 50%;
      position:absolute;
      top: -45%;
      transform: translate(10rem, 10rem) rotate(135deg);
      width:10%;
    }
   }
  .bottom-border {
    height: 12rem;
    width: 10rem;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 40%, 50% 0);
    border-radius: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    .bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    height: 8.8rem;
    background: white;
    width: 6.8rem;
    clip-path: polygon(100% 45%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 45%, 50% 5%);
    overflow: hidden;
      &:before {
      animation:bottom $time linear infinite;
      background-color:$color;
      border-radius:50%;
      content:"";
      display:block;
      height: 10rem;
      left: -23%;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      transform:translateY(100%);
      width: 10rem;
    }
    &:after {
      animation:bottom-drip $time linear infinite;
      background-color:$color;
      content:"";
      display:block;
      height:100%;
      left:45%;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      width:10%;
    }
    }
  }
}

@keyframes flip {
  0%, 45% {
    transform:rotate(0);
  }
  50%, 95% {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bottom {
  0% {
    transform:translateY(100%);
  }
  50% {
    transform:translateY(-5%);
  }
  51% {
    transform:translateY(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translateY(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes top {
  0% {
    transform:translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  50% {
    transform:translate(8rem, 8rem);
  }
  51% {
    transform:translate(-7rem, -7rem);
  }
  100% {
    transform:translate(1rem, 1rem);
  }
}

@keyframes bottom-drip {
  0% {
    left:45%;
    transform:translateY(-100%);
    width:10%;
  }
  5% {
    transform:translateY(0);
  }
  45%, 100% {
    left:50%;
    transform:translateY(0);
    width:0;
  }
}

@keyframes top-drip {
  0%, 50% {
    left:45%;
    top: -50%;
    transform:translate(10rem, 10rem) rotate(135deg);
    width:10%;
  }
  55% {
    left:45%;
    top: -50%;
    transform:translate(0, 0) rotate(135deg);
    width:10%;
  }
  100% {
    left:50%;
    top: -50%;
    transform:translate(0, 0) rotate(135deg);
    width:0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tested this in Firefox and there's no glitchy line.  Tested it in Chrome, and there is.  It doesn't answer the question, but narrows it down a bit.